# function toggle - open all items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle

guys

I have a following HTML code with wrap (notice-wrap):

```
<div class="notice-title">
    Title
</div>

<div class="notice-content">
    Content text
</div>

<div class="notice-toggle" value="Hide" onclick="toggle()">
    <a href="#"><img src="../img/icon_rollout.png"></a>
</div>
```

And Toggle Script

```
    function toggle() {
    var newStatus = $('.notice-toggle').val() === "Hide" ? "Show" : "Hide";
    $('.notice-toggle').val(newStatus);
    if (newStatus == "Show") {
        $("div.notice-content").css('overflow','hidden');
        $("div.notice-content").css('height','80px');
        $("div.notice-wrap").css('height','187px');
    }
    else {
        $("div.notice-content").css('overflow','visible');
        $("div.notice-content").css('height','100%');
        $("div.notice-wrap").css('height','100%');
    }
}
```

When i'm clicking on the toggle, open once all the items. How to make the opening only that element which i choose?

P.S. I also use Angular

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to add details about the bind of the function to the html tag, so we can understand how to help you

Comment: I edited the post, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can just change this:

```
function toggle() {
    var newStatus = $('.notice-toggle').val() === "Hide" ? "Show" : "Hide";
    $('.notice-toggle').val(newStatus);
    if (newStatus == "Show") {
        $("div.notice-content").css('overflow','hidden');
        $("div.notice-content").css('height','80px');
        $("div.notice-wrap").css('height','187px');
    }
    else {
        $("div.notice-content").css('overflow','visible');
        $("div.notice-content").css('height','100%');
        $("div.notice-wrap").css('height','100%');
    }
}
```

to:

```
function toggle() {
    var noticeToggleElement = $(this);
    var newStatus = noticeToggleElement.val() === "Hide" ? "Show" : "Hide";
    noticeToggleElement.val(newStatus);
    if (newStatus == "Show") {
        noticeToggleElement.css('overflow','hidden');
        noticeToggleElement.css('height','80px');
        $("div.notice-wrap").css('height','187px');
    }
    else {
        noticeToggleElement.css('overflow','visible');
        noticeToggleElement.css('height','100%');
        $("div.notice-wrap").css('height','100%');
    }
}
```

As you should have the context of the element you toggle on with the mouse click.

As you're using jQuery, should be better if you remove the onclick from the HTML tag and make the bind in your javascript code, on a function that is executed on document ready:

```
$(function(){

    $('div.notice-content').click(toggle);

})
```

But this is just a plus.

Comment: This code looks pretty good, but now i have this error "Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"

Comment: You should have another problem, as it is not called in the toggle function, could you get the line?

Comment: Yes, i understand... You mean the line with error?  hooks = jQuery.valHooks[ elem.type ] || jQuery.valHooks[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() ];

Comment: the `nodeName` is undefined for some reason. Is this part in your toggle function? If not please fell free to create a new question.

Comment: No, it's connected somehow with jquery.

Thank you a lot for your time and help! Appreciate this

Answer (score 0):

What you should do first is move that styling from js to css,
and have additional variations of your classes, for example:

```
.notice-title--toggled {
...
}

.notice-content--toggled {
...
}

.notice-toggle--toggled {
...
}
```

Now you have good separation of concerns, and your toggle function could just toggle classes for those elements.
Also you should put this toggle click handler on document ready, so final result would be:

```
$(function) {
  $('.notice-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.notice-title').toggleClass('notice-title--toggled');
    $('.notice-content').toggleClass('notice-content--toggled');
    $('.notice-toggle').toggleClass('notice-toggle--toggled');
  });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue, just do the same work, with the issue, in a different way.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini my comment was more about teaching some good practices, and not providing copy/paste solutions

Comment: @DejanRainsavijevic your intentions are good, but this is not the CodeReview, and you should say your answer did not solve the issue.